# Text cut off after migration in some fields

Tags: craft3, migration

I migrated a site from Craft 2 to Craft 3 and on some Redactor fields, half the text is gone. It looks completely random. In some fields, the text is gone. In some the text is about half as long as before and on others the text is fine. How is this possible?

I just noticed that when I copy the old text into the field it is cut off again on save. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue with the awesome Craft support.

There seems to be a server related issue where db tables change from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR`.

So the solution is to change those fields back to `TEXT` directly in the db.